# remote desktop connection from windows to linux using c#.net

Tags: c#

while develop in c# for rdp we use basically using MSTSCLib; but connecting linux this dll not supporting. So, what dll have to use for rdp from windows to linux in c# application.

namespace SampleRDC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            rdp.Server = txtServer.Text;
            rdp.UserName = txtUserName.Text;

            IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();
            secured.ClearTextPassword = txtPassword.Text;
            rdp.Connect();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting", "Error connecting to remote desktop " + txtServer.Text + " Error:  " + Ex.Message,MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Check if connected before disconnecting
            if (rdp.Connected.ToString() == "1")
                rdp.Disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Disconnecting", "Error disconnecting from remote desktop " + txtServer.Text + " Error:  " + Ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

}

based on this program how to write for windows to linux through remote desktop

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), you can't RDP into a linux machine from Windows put you can use a protocol called SSH, it does not have a GUI and everything is text based.

Answer (score 0):

RDP is native to Windows. 
If you want Linux to act as RDP server, check out XRDP at http://sourceforge.net/projects/xrdp/

For Linux, you can SSH (which Putty supports).
Another option is to enable VNC server, which most Linux distros support.